# I want to start windows 10 ubuntu environment automatically after the computer logs in

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using windows 10, and the ubuntu environment that can be downloaded from the windows start or by installing it visa the CMD typing bash to get started.

How could I start this ubuntu environment inside of windows 10 on startup?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish Ubuntu to start when you logon, put its link in
your Startup folder, located at:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```